# Binary Search Tree Iterate non-keys

Tags: java, printing, binary-search-tree

I have a bit of a conundrum.  I need to print all the values in my BST that are NOT keys.  So since the tree is not ordered according to these values, I can't do as I normally have with BSTs in the past.  I simply need to look at EVERY node on the tree, compare the non-key value with the value I have entered, and determine whether to print it.

I.E. Student directory where I need to print all GPAs above a 2.0.  Since the tree is ordered by Student IDs and not GPA, how do I go through every node and compare GPA and print all nodes that are above 2.0?

If you need to look at my code, the whole thing is here, and it's enormous.

```
public class StudentBST
{
private static Node root;

static class Node
{
    public int studentID;
    public String lastName;
    public String firstName;
    public String major;
    public double gpa;
    public Node left, right;

    public int minValue()
    {
        if(left == null)
        {
            return studentID;
        }
        else
        {
            return left.minValue();
        }
    }

    public boolean remove(int i, Node node)
    {
        if(i < this.studentID)
        {
            if(left != null)
            {
                return left.remove(i, this);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if(i > this.studentID)
        {
            if(right != null)
            {
                return right.remove(i, this);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(left != null && right != null)
            {
                this.studentID = right.minValue();
                right.remove(this.studentID, this);
            }
            else if(node.left == this)
            {
                node.left = (left != null) ? left : right;
            }
            else if(node.right == this)
            {
                node.right = (left != null) ? left : right;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Node(int i, String l, String f, String m, double g)
    {
    studentID = i;
    lastName = l;
    firstName = f;
    major = m;
    gpa = g;
    left = null;
    right = null;
    }
}
public StudentBST()
{
    root = null;
}
private static void insert(int i, String l, String f, String m, double g)
{
    root = insert(root, i, l, f, m , g);
}
private static Node insert(Node node, int i, String l, String f, String m, double g)
{
    if(node == null)
    {
        node = new Node(i, l, f, m, g);
    }
    else
    {
        if(i <= node.studentID)
        {
            node.left = insert(node.left, i, l, f, m, g);
        }
        else
        {
            node.right = insert(node.right, i, l, f, m, g);
        }
    }
    return(node);
}
public static void printBST()
{
    printBST(root);
    System.out.println();
}
private static void printBST(Node node)
{
    if(node == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    printBST(node.left);
    System.out.println(node.studentID + ", " + node.lastName + ", " + node.firstName
    + ", " + node.major + ", " + node.gpa);
    printBST(node.right);
}
public static boolean remove(int i)
{
    if(root == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if(root.studentID == i)
        {
            Node auxRoot = new Node(0, "", "", "", 0);
            auxRoot.left = root;
            boolean result = root.remove(i, auxRoot);
            root = auxRoot.left;
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return root.remove(i, null);
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    StudentBST.insert(8, "Costanza", "George", "Napping", 1.60);
    StudentBST.insert(10, "Kramer", "Cosmo", "Chemistry", 3.04);
    StudentBST.insert(5, "Seinfeld", "Jerry", "Theater", 2.05);

    StudentBST.printBST();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int option = 9;

    while(option != 0)
    {
        System.out.println("1 - Add new student 2 - Delete student 3 - Print All" + 
                " 0 - Exit");
        option = input.nextInt();

        if(option == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter student ID");
            int i = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter Last Name");
            String l = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter First Name");
            String f = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter major");
            String m = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter GPA");
            Double g = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("Inserted student record");
            StudentBST.insert(i, l, f, m, g);
        }
        if(option == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter Student ID to delete");
            int i = input.nextInt();
            boolean b = StudentBST.remove(i);
            if(b)
            {
                System.out.println("Deletion completed");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Deletion encountered error");
            }
        }
        if(option == 3)
        {
            StudentBST.printBST();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have the right idea: just walk across the whole tree and print out GPAs higher than a certain threshold. A rough implementation looks like:

```
public void printGPAs(Node node, double gpa_cutoff) {
    if (node == null) {
        return;
    } 

    if (node.gpa >= gpa_cutoff) {
        System.out.println(node.gpa);
    }

    printGPAs(node.left);
    printGPAs(node.right);
}
```

If you wanted to print them out in a particular order, the easiest way would be to drop them in to a list as you go along, inserting in the correct place to maintain your desired order.

Comment: No problem -- it sounds like you were just confused by the idea of working with the tree in a "nonstandard" way